# Endianness of JavaScript integer literals

Tags: javascript, integer, endianness, literals

If I write

```
var n = 0x1234
```

in Javascript, is

```
n == 4660
```

always true? The question can also stated this way: Does 0x1234 denote a sequence of bytes with 0x12 being the first and 0x34 being the last byte? Or does 0x1234 denote a number to the base 16 with the left digit being the most signigicant?

In the first case 0x1234 might be 4660 if interpreted as big endian and 13330 if interpreted as little endian.

In the latter case 0x1234 always equals 1 * 4096 + 2 * 256 + 3 * 16 + 4 = 4660.

Comment: The `0x` prefix is just hex notation; it's not about bit/byte ordering. The leftmost digit is always the most significant.

Comment: There is no such concept as endianess of literals.. in any language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `0x` notation in JS *always* represents a number with base 16 with the left digit being the most significant.